# Angular and Firestore: Get UID user athenticated to query in constructor

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm new to Angular 2.x and Firebase.

I'm trying to get the UID of the authenticated user to make a query in Firestore. The UID is returning the value in console.log, but apparently I can't put it in my query to make the query. Here's how I did it:

```
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe( user => {
      this.usuariosRef = db.collection(this.dbPath, ref => ref.where('userId', '==', user.uid));
    });
    console.log(this.afAuth.authState);

  }
```

Is that the best solution to do this?

Comment: What's the problem with this code? E.g. which line in here doesn't do what you expect it to do? It's often easiest to show us the problem by also including a `console.log` line that **doesn't** do what you expect it  to do.

Answer (score 0):

`db.collection` returns `Observable` so you need to subscribe to that as well

or using `switchMap` and subscribing once.

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.afAuth.authState
    .pipe( 
        switchMap(user => db.collection(this.dbPath, ref => ref.where('userId', '==', user.uid)))
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })

    console.log(this.afAuth.authState);

  }
```

p.s These codes usually should be placed inside `ngOnInit()` not in `constructor`